# ServiceConfigurationError when using Hibernate SPI MetadataContributor

Tags: java, spring-boot, hibernate, spi

Hi someone a clue how to integrate a MetadataContributor in a Spring Boot application without errors?

I got:

```
java.util.ServiceConfigurationError: org.hibernate.boot.spi.MetadataContributor: Provider com.example.demo.TestContributor not found
at java.base/java.util.ServiceLoader.fail(ServiceLoader.java:588) ~[na:na]
at java.base/java.util.ServiceLoader$LazyClassPathLookupIterator.nextProviderClass(ServiceLoader.java:1211) ~[na:na]
at java.base/java.util.ServiceLoader$LazyClassPathLookupIterator.hasNextService(ServiceLoader.java:1220) ~[na:na]
at java.base/java.util.ServiceLoader$LazyClassPathLookupIterator.hasNext(ServiceLoader.java:1264) ~[na:na]
at java.base/java.util.ServiceLoader$2.hasNext(ServiceLoader.java:1299) ~[na:na]
at java.base/java.util.ServiceLoader$ProviderSpliterator.tryAdvance(ServiceLoader.java:1483) ~[na:na]
at java.base/java.util.Spliterators$1Adapter.hasNext(Spliterators.java:681) ~[na:na]
at org.hibernate.boot.registry.classloading.internal.AggregatedServiceLoader$ClassPathAndModulePathAggregatedServiceLoader.hasNextIgnoringServiceConfigurationError(AggregatedServiceLoader.java:241) ~[hibernate-core-5.4.27.Final.jar!/:5.4.27.Final]
at org.hibernate.boot.registry.classloading.internal.AggregatedServiceLoader$ClassPathAndModulePathAggregatedServiceLoader.loadAll(AggregatedServiceLoader.java:219) ~[hibernate-core-5.4.27.Final.jar!/:5.4.27.Final]
at org.hibernate.boot.registry.classloading.internal.AggregatedServiceLoader$ClassPathAndModulePathAggregatedServiceLoader.getAll(AggregatedServiceLoader.java:187) ~[hibernate-core-5.4.27.Final.jar!/:5.4.27.Final]
at org.hibernate.boot.registry.classloading.internal.ClassLoaderServiceImpl.loadJavaServices(ClassLoaderServiceImpl.java:251) ~[hibernate-core-5.4.27.Final.jar!/:5.4.27.Final]
at org.hibernate.boot.model.process.spi.MetadataBuildingProcess.complete(MetadataBuildingProcess.java:290) ~[hibernate-core-5.4.27.Final.jar!/:5.4.27.Final]
...
```

I have a fresh spring boot project with just

```xml
    <dependency>
      <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
      <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-data-jpa</artifactId>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
      <groupId>com.h2database</groupId>
      <artifactId>h2</artifactId>
      <scope>runtime</scope>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
      <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
      <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-test</artifactId>
      <scope>test</scope>
    </dependency>
```

Added a contributor
package com.example.demo;

```
public class TestContributor implements MetadataContributor {
  Logger logger = LoggerFactory.getLogger(TestContributor.class);
  @Override
  public void contribute(InFlightMetadataCollector metadataCollector, IndexView jandexIndex) {
    logger.info("Still works");
  }
}
```

And added `src/main/resources/META-INF/services/org.hibernate.boot.spi.MetadataContributor` file with class definition

```
com.example.demo.TestContributor
```

When I start the project via Intellij everything works.
But when I build a jar `mvn clean package` and try to start it via jar `java -jar demo-0.0.1-SNAPSHOT.jar` I get the problem from above.

It still works cause the other classloaders seems to work fine. I tried to debug into Hibernate but I don't understand what the problem is. Someone has an idea?

Comment: Do you have the spring boot plugin configured?

Comment: What do you mean with spring boot plugin configured? Hibernate SPI should work independet from spring boot. I think it's the spring boot maven repackaging mechanism that breaks the things.

Comment: I doubt that that is breaking things. The class isn't found which means it isn't on the classpath. Hence my suggestion that you might have configured something wrongly. But without seeing what you have actually done that is hard to see.

Comment: Did you check the produced JAR if it contains a file named `META-INF/services/org.hibernate.boot.spi.MetadataContributor` with the correct class name in it? Maybe you misconfigured the packaging.

Comment: @M.Deinum it's easy just take spring initializer create the default with spring-boot-starter-data-jpa and h2 add the class as described above and you get the problem. Did nothing else.
ChristianBeikov yes it is in the jar. 2 of 3 classloader find the class during hibernate boot up. The code will executed once but still there is a big warning that the class couldn't be found. My current workaround is to ignore the warning :/ cause its just a warning.

Comment: I'm not going to create a project myself as it wouldn't be the first time I did that and it worked on my machine. So I want you to do it and show us.

Comment: @M.Deinum did you tried to start the spring build jar or directly from IDE? When I start from IDE it works. Maybe its Java 11? Which Java version you are using?

Comment: As stated I didn't try anything as I want **you** to make a project which we can try. I'm not going to make something myself, because as stated as well, it wouldn't be the first (nor the last) time something worked for me and not for others.